# Exclude folder in htaccess from www redirect

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a www redirect in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example/ [R=permanent]
```

Now I would like to exclude one folder to use the above redirect. 
I would like to access a folder without being redirected to the domain with www. 
For example: 
What I want: example.com/test
What happens: www.example.com/test

Can I exclude only the folder test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^test/ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,NE,R=302]
```

Make sure this rule is first rule just below `RewriteEngine On` line your root .htaccess (one directory level above `/test/`).